# Declaration errors when depyoing TypeScript to Heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, npm, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my TypeScript API to Heroku. I have a heroku-prebuild script running `npm i && npm i -g typescript && npm run build` and a build script running `tsc`.

So I had installed some new packages with their corresponding types decalrations, and got errors from Heroku:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.4...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.6
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Prebuild
       Running heroku-prebuild
       
       > swooosh-api@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild /tmp/build_fc3ad6d3
       > npm i && npm i -g typescript && npm run build
       
       audited 237 packages in 2.088s
       
       12 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       /tmp/build_fc3ad6d3/.heroku/node/bin/tsc -> /tmp/build_fc3ad6d3/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
       /tmp/build_fc3ad6d3/.heroku/node/bin/tsserver -> /tmp/build_fc3ad6d3/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
       + typescript@4.0.3
       added 1 package from 1 contributor in 1.843s
       
       > swooosh-api@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_fc3ad6d3
       > tsc
       
       api/utils/config.ts(1,23): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express-rate-limit'. '/tmp/build_fc3ad6d3/node_modules/express-rate-limit/lib/express-rate-limit.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
         Try `npm install @types/express-rate-limit` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express-rate-limit';`
       api/utils/config.ts(2,22): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express-slow-down'. '/tmp/build_fc3ad6d3/node_modules/express-slow-down/lib/express-slow-down.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
         Try `npm install @types/express-slow-down` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express-slow-down';`
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! swooosh-api@1.0.0 build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the swooosh-api@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.saClh/_logs/2020-10-04T13_30_28_587Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! swooosh-api@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild: `npm i && npm i -g typescript && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the swooosh-api@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.saClh/_logs/2020-10-04T13_30_28_605Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I thought the problem was that Heroku caches the `node_modules` folder. But I turned that off and I had declaration errors for every single packages...

GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/herbievine/swooosh-api)

How can I fix this?

Comment: `heroku-prebuild` runs before Heroku installs dependencies, which is why you have to install yourself; why don't you just let Heroku install then run `build`?

Comment: So the build command in package.json runs automatically?

Comment: Yes, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

Comment: Great thanks! Do you want to post an answer so I can mark as correct?

Comment: It's not an answer, that doesn't explain why your current setup doesn't work when it runs the install itself.

Comment: Well, when it builds it works so... And do I even need the pre-build stage?